# Not able to install Folly on Fedora 31

Tags: c++, fedora, folly

I'm not able to compile on Fedora 31. I installed fmt and followed these instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/folly.git
cd folly
mkdir _build
cd _build
cmake ..
```

When I run `cmake ..`, I get the following error:

```
[vagrant@localhost _build]$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR context filesystem
  program_options regex system thread) (Required is at least version
  "1.51.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMake/folly-deps.cmake:36 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:113 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/vagrant/folly/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/vagrant/folly/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: `Could NOT find Boost ...`  Are you sure that you have `Boost` installed?

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks